# How to raw_input data when using user defined functions:

Tags: python

Hi i am new to programming and just started learning python i wrote the below code /program to prompt hours and rate per hour using raw_input to compute gross pay. i tried to initiate time-and-a-half for the hourly rate for all hours worked above 40 hours. the logic to do the computation of time-and-a-half in a function called computepay() and use the function to do the computation. The function should return a value. i used 45 hours and a rate of 10.50 per hour to test the program (the pay should return 498.75). i tried using raw_input to read a string and float() to convert the string to a number. i Don't name my variable sum or use the sum() function. i am able to print the output but i need to input the data when prompted unlike inputing the value in "line16"

```
def computePay (hours,rate):
    if hours > 40:
        overtimerate = 1.5 * rate
        overtime = (hours-40) * overtimerate
        overtimepay = overtime + (40 * rate)
        return overtimepay;
    else:
        normalpay = hours * rate
        return normalpay;
hours = raw_input('Enter hours: ')
hrs = int(hours)
rate = raw_input('Enter rate: ')
r = float(rate)
p = computePay(45,10.50)
print p
```

Comment: What's your question, exactly? Why do you take input then ignore it? Also the indentation in your code sample is all over the place, please fix it and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just use the variables that hold the data you want: `p = computePay(hrs,r)`.

Comment: tdelaney, thanks a lot for taking time and reviewing my request. i tried P = computePay(hrs, r) but getting an error "You must use a function called computepay to do the computation."

Comment: You're told you're asked for a `computepay` function, but your function is called `computePay`... Is this a typo?

Comment: Where is the raw_input coming from? Is this submitted online? Make sure everything is spelled how they want it

Comment: @Right leg , thanks for the inputs.computePay is a typo. this code is submitted online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumptions**:

I had to make the following assumptions in understanding your question:

1. Looking at your print statement, You are using python2.x
2. You want to computePay using the user inputted hours and rate.

**Problem**:

In the following line you are using constant hrs and r values instead of using the user inputed values

```
p = computePay(45,10.50)
```

**Solution**:

If you want to use user inputted values to compute the pay, you need to call the function as follows:

```
p = computePay(hrs, r)
```

With this line you are essentially asking python to computePay using the values stored in the variables hrs and r.

**Final Code:**

Therefore your final code should like this:

```
def computePay (hours,rate):
    if hours > 40:
        overtimerate = 1.5 * rate
        overtime = (hours-40) * overtimerate
        overtimepay = overtime + (40 * rate)
        return overtimepay;
    else:
        normalpay = hours * rate
        return normalpay;
hours = raw_input('Enter hours: ')
hrs = int(hours)
rate = raw_input('Enter rate: ')
r = float(rate)
p = computePay(hrs,r)
print p
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter hours: 55
Enter rate: 20
1250.0
```

Comment: thanks a lot for taking time and reviewing my request. i tried  P = coumputePay(hrs, r) but getting an error "You must use a function called computepay to do the computation."

Comment: @vgrg Can you please post the code you are using now? and the actual error python is giving out.

Couple of sanity checks:
1. You need to define computePay function before calling it. 
2. You can try copy pasting the "final code" from my solution. It should work.

Comment: code below..1) yes! you are correct,i am trying to define computePay function before calling it. 2) i tried copying your code but its the same error #You must use a function called computepay to do the computation.#

Comment: def computePay (hours,rate):
    if hours > 40:
        overtimerate = 1.5 * rate
        overtime = (hours-40) * overtimerate
        overtimepay = overtime + (40 * rate)
        return overtimepay;
    else:
        normalpay = hours * rate
        return normalpay;
hours = raw_input('Enter hours: ')
hrs = int(hours)
rate = raw_input('Enter rate: ')
r = float(rate)
p = computePay(hrs,r)
print p

Comment: @vgrg As others have pointed out, Python is case sensitive. So there is computepay is a different fucntion from computePay. So I suggest you upload a screenshot of your code and your error as an edit in your question. Then we might be able to better understand the issue.

Comment: thanks a lot for you support, much appreciated. i got it its just case sensitive thing which i missed, i typed computePay instead of computpay. all sorted now thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by that you want the arguments to equal the inputs rather than the ones inputted manually, you should do instead:

```
p = computePay(hrs, r)
```

Example output:

```
Enter hours: 45
Enter rate: 10.5
498.75
```

Comment: Anthony, thanks a lot for taking time and reviewing my request. i tried P = computePay(hrs, r) but getting an error "You must use a function called computepay to do the computation."